# Angular-ui + D3: how to implement contextual menu (popover vs modal)?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, modal-dialog, popover, angular-ui

**Given the following use-case:**

I use D3js to render objects which are managed by AngularJS. I would like to add interactivity to the D3 chart. When clicking on a svg element I would like to have a kind of popup menu allowing to modify the object properties. These properties are required by AngularJS but are not rendered by D3.

The D3-Angular integration is derived from http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/5372077 which uses a closure.

**Current implementation:**

As of today I am using the $modal service from angular-ui bootstrap to create the popup menu. From a functionnality point of view it works pretty well:
    When clicking on a svg element, D3 dispatches an event
    That event is catched by Angular which calls the $modal service
    Within the modal window I modify the object properties

However I am not satisfied with the rendering. I would like the popup menu to look like a popover. It should be placed close to the svg element which was clicked.

As far as I understand, I have **two options**:

1. Continue to use the $modal service and modify its look. What approach should be taken? Using the windowClass option?
2. Stop using the $modal service and start hacking on the popover directive. The problem is that I do not think it is possible
   to add such a directive to an svg element. The solution would be to
   create a popover service close to the $modal service.

Which option should be chosen? and how to implement it?

**EDIT:**

Working plunker using a custom my-popover directive:
http://plnkr.co/edit/5KYvxi?p=preview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to add a directives to code generated by `d3`, only thing you need to ensure is that you call the [`$compile`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) service on the content after it has been rendered.

For the given example, it would look something like this:

```js
    .directive('barChart', function($compile){  // inject $compile
        var chart = d3.custom.barChart();
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: '<div class="chart"></div>',
            scope:{
                height: '=height',
                data: '=data',
                hovered: '&hovered'
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var chartEl = d3.select(element[0]);
                chart.on('customHover', function(d, i){
                    scope.hovered({args:d});
                });

                scope.$watch('data', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                    chartEl.datum(newVal).call(chart);
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);   // <-- call to $compile
                });

                scope.$watch('height', function(d, i){
                    chartEl.call(chart.height(scope.height));
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope); // <-- call to $compile
                })
            }
        }
```

And in the `d3`'s drawing function:

```js
       bars.enter().append('rect')
            .classed('bar', true)
            .attr('myPopover', 'Text to show') // <-- Adding an attribute here.
            .attr({x: chartW,
                width: barW,
                y: function(d, i) { return y1(d); },
                height: function(d, i) { return chartH - y1(d); }
            })
            .on('mouseover', dispatch.customHover);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/5KYvxi?p=preview)

Comment: thanks. I tried your solution with the popover directive from angular-ui bootstrap and could note make it work. Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZjNZChVPlBUDWPxGhuEL?p=preview A popover should be opened when clicking on a bar but it is not.

Comment: I have made many changes to the plunker: fixed spelling of `content` to `contents`, added `bootstrap.{js,css}`, wrote directive `myPopover` which uses `tooltip` internally. The [position calculation in `ui.angular`](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/position/position.js#L69) is broken, when [compared to the actual implementation](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/tooltip.js#L295). Hence, `ui.bootstrap` will work, but the position calculated for `svg` elements is incorrect. I'll file a bug report/fix for it later. Demo added to the answer.

Comment: Created a pull request for the fix: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/1225

Comment: The pull request has been merged in and now using `popover` with the latest build of `ui.bootstrap` should work as well.