# How to bind an angularjs directive to a d3js node defined in a link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I would like to use a d3js graph in an AngularJs app, and then bind directives to the nodes.

First I put the js code in the link function of a directive and everything works well.

```
angular.module('myApp', []).

directive('grapheForces', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var width = 450;
            var height = 400;
            var color = d3.scale.category20();

            scope.$watch('grapheDatas', function (grapheDatas) {
                var force = d3.layout.force()
                .charge(-120)
                .linkDistance(30)
                .size([width, height])
                .nodes(grapheDatas.nodes)
                .links(grapheDatas.links)
                .start();

                var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

                var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                .data(grapheDatas.links)
                .enter().append("line")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

                var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(grapheDatas.nodes)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("r", 5)
                .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
                .call(force.drag);

                node.append("title")
                .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

                force.on("tick", function() {
                    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

                    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
                });
            });
        }
    }
}).
```

And then I would like to add a tooltip to the nodes, so I go :

```
                var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .attr("tooltip", function(){
                    return "tooltipTextHere";
                 });
```

As I use angular-bootstrap, tooltip is a directive.
The tooltip attribute is well present in the html result :

```
<circle tooltip="tooltipTextHere" class="nodeCircle" r="4.5" style="fill: #b0c4de;"></circle>
```

But the tooltip is ineffective, and so it goes for every directive I bind like that.

I guess it is because the directive has not been taken in account during the compile phase, but I can't find how to do that as I reach my current comprehension limits in AngularJs.

Do you have an idea of how i could make it happen ??
Thank you very much for your very valuable answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have answered a very similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399336/how-do-i-use-angularjs-directives-in-generated-d3-html/). You can see the full answer there.

Basically, after you add the tooltip attributes, you need to remove your custom directive attribute with something like `element.removeAttr("graphe-forces")` and then run `$compile(element)(scope)` so the app will find the tooltip directive.

Here's a [fiddle of a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/5py6s/).

Comment: Totally awesome thanks a lot. The tooltip is still not showing however, but this is a display problem as I can see it appear in the html code.

Comment: No problem! If you still can't get the tooltip to appear, post a fiddle or plunker and we can help with that, too.