# Get Angular to action ng-if in new elements generated by d3.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I am generating a series of `<circle ng-if='n'> someScopeFunction()' \>` with d3.js

How can I get Angular to notice and work on these new elements and ng-ifs?

And how can I get it to do so with angular variables, e.g. `<circle some-attr='{{i - 2}}' />`

Comment: You might be looking for something like [this](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ng-if is a directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf), you can use this solution:
[How do I use angularjs directives in generated d3 html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399336/how-do-i-use-angularjs-directives-in-generated-d3-html)

The only supposition is that you d3 is already in a directive.

Comment: I was tempted to flag as duplicated but the concept that ng-if is a directive is not always clear.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap them with a `scope`. Maybe a Controller. I also suggests you to not use `ng-if` if you just want to hide/show them, since its expensive. You better use `ng-show` / `ng-hide`

Or maybe look for a solution like [angular-nvd3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `$compile` service as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11700766/511387), though I would recommend using Angular to generate and insert `<circle>`. I wrote a [blog post](http://blog.modernadvisor.ca/engineering/taming-d3-with-angularjs/) on D3 + Angular that you might find helpful.